# Tests don't work on Xcode 8, beta 2

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, automated-tests, xcode8, xcode8-beta2

When I run tests on my project in XCode, it builds, and then says `Testing...` which never ends.

When I use the stop button, the process stops with this text in the console:

```
*** If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Users/MY.NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-gcsubmsjksdbljcswbefkgugjray/Logs/Test/C53D8988-3564-4C2B-A535-075D26D1E4A7/Session-APPNAMETests-2016-07-13_140704-t3DFd5.log
```

However, I am unable to run the tests again, and have to relaunch xcode to run them.

Is this an issue on XCode that may be known to the Apple developers?

**EDIT**

So, I figured, the simulator is not launching in time, and that fails the xcode to run the tests. It might be an installation bug with the simulator.

Comment: The only way to know that is to file a bug report. You will probably want to capture a `sysdiagnose`.

Comment: Please capture a video recording of the issue and take a sysdiagnose while in the hung state.  Send both in a bug report to http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Happens to me on both the Simulator and on my real device, in Xcode 8 GM. Thanks, Apple!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I anticipated in my edit to the question the first time, XCode installation did not install the simulator correctly. 
I trashed the old installed version and reinstalled XCode. And now everything works fine.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Works fine in the Beta, or back to the standard version? I have the same issue

Answer (score 4):

I found that the tests never ran if I was running anything other than iOS10 on the simulator, so use iOS 10.  I guess backwards compatibility doesn't really matter.

Comment: Confirms my experience as well. Thanks for this answer!